# NSNotification subclass with Generics in Swift 2.1

Tags: swift, generics, nsnotificationcenter

Can't make subclass of NSNotification with Generic `payload` object. Getting either runtime error or compile error (see comments in code below). Is it even possible with Swift 2.1? Any ideas appreciated. Thanks!

*Runtime error* because NSNotification is abstract class (class cluster).
*Compile error* because designated initializer should be used.

```
public class Notification<T: Any>: NSNotification {

    private var _name: String
    private var _object: AnyObject?
    private var _payload: T?

    public override var name: String {
        return _name
    }

    public override var object: AnyObject? {
        return _object
    }

    public var payload: T? {
        return _payload
    }

    /// Always nil. Use payload
    public override var userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]? {
        return nil
    }

    /// Change to false to "swap" implementation
    #if true

    init(name: String, object: AnyObject? = nil, payload: T? = nil) {
        _name = name
        _object = object
        _payload = payload
        /*
          Runtime error:
          Terminating app due to uncaught exception
          'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
          '*** initialization method -initWithName:object:userInfo:
          cannot be sent to an abstract object of class
          _TtGC14__lldb_expr_1612NotificationSS_:
          Create a concrete instance!'
        */
        super.init(name: name, object: object, userInfo: nil)
    }

    #else

    convenience init(name: String, object: AnyObject? = nil, payload: T? = nil) {
        self.init()
        _name = name
        _object = object
        _payload = payload
    }

    init() {
        /// compiler error:
        /// must call a designated initializer of the superclass
        /// But using designated initializer cause runtime error listed above.
        super.init() 
    }

    #endif
}


let n = Notification<String>(name: "xyz", payload: "Hello")
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[From the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotification_Class/), emphasis mine:

> You can subclass `NSNotification` to contain information in addition to the notification name, object, and dictionary. This extra data must be agreed upon between notifiers and observers.
>
> `NSNotification` is a class cluster with no instance variables. As such, you must subclass `NSNotification` and override the primitive methods `name`, `object`, and `userInfo`. You can choose any designated initializer you like, but be sure that your initializer does not call `[super init]`. *`NSNotification` is not meant to be instantiated directly, and its `init` method raises an exception.*

There's no way subclass `NSNotification` from Swift code right now, as Swift has no concept of "uninitializable classes" and requires that all subclasses invoke their superclass's `init` (which, in this case, is the wrong thing to do).

You'll have to write the subclass in Objective-C and bridge it into your Swift code.

Unfortunately, even though you *can* declare your Objective-C class generic, that information is lost in the bridging process. [From the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithObjective-CAPIs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH4-ID173):

> Aside from these Foundation collection classes, Objective-C lightweight generics are ignored by Swift. Any other types using lightweight generics are imported into Swift as if they were unparameterized.

:(

Answer (score 1):

I solved original problem without subclassing.

File **GenericNotification.swift**:

```
private let genericNotificationPayloadKey = "com.mc.notification-payload"

class GenericNotification<T: Any> {

   let payload: T
   let name: NSNotification.Name
   let object: Any?

   init(name: NSNotification.Name, object: Any? = nil, payload: T) {
      self.name = name
      self.object = object
      self.payload = payload
   }

   init?(notification: Notification) {
      guard let payload = notification.userInfo?[genericNotificationPayloadKey] as? T else {
         return nil
      }
      self.payload = payload
      name = notification.name
      object = notification.object
   }
}

extension GenericNotification {

   var notification: Notification {
      return Notification(name: name, object: object, userInfo: [genericNotificationPayloadKey: payload])
   }

   static func observe(name: NSNotification.Name,
                       object: Any? = nil,
                       queue: OperationQueue = .main,
                       handler: @escaping (T) -> Void) -> NotificationObserver {
      return NotificationObserver(name: name, object: object, queue: queue) {
         if let notification = GenericNotification(notification: $0) {
            handler(notification.payload)
         }
      }
   }

   func post(center: NotificationCenter = NotificationCenter.default) {
      center.post(notification)
   }
}
```

File **NotificationObserver.swift**:

```
class NotificationObserver: NSObject {

   typealias Handler = ((Foundation.Notification) -> Void)

   private var notificationObserver: NSObjectProtocol!
   var notificationHandler: Handler?
   private let notificationName: NSNotification.Name
   private let notificationObject: Any?

   init(name: NSNotification.Name, object: Any? = nil, queue: OperationQueue = .main, handler: Handler? = nil) {
      notificationName = name
      notificationObject = object
      notificationHandler = handler
      super.init()
      notificationObserver = NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: name, object: object, queue: queue) { [weak self] in
         self?.handleNotification($0)
      }
   }

   deinit {
      NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(notificationObserver, name: notificationName, object: notificationObject)
   }

   /// Calls block which was passed as *usingBlock* parameter.
   /// Child classes may override to change default behaviour.
   /// - parameter notification: Notification to handle.
   func handleNotification(_ notification: Foundation.Notification) {
      notificationHandler?(notification)
   }
}
```

**Usage**:

```
// Send notification
let action = MyType.doSomething
GenericNotification(name: .myNotificationName, payload: action).post()

// Receive notification
private var notificationObservers: [NotificationObserver] = []
...
notificationObservers.append(GenericNotification<MyType>.observe(name: .myNotificationName) { instanceOfMyType in
    // Got `instanceOfMyType` which is `MyType.doSomething`
})
```